# Canvas - saving to image with php or js

Tags: javascript, php, image-processing, canvas, save

I have a canvas element and want to name it and save it as a jpg in my file system.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
console.log(dataURL)
```

I can use either PHP or JS.

Is this possible? It seems like it should be easy.

Comment: PHP if it's on your server JS if it's on client computer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Getting url as base64 create a dynamic link with hreaf as data url and click to force download and then remove link

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
console.log(dataURL);

 var e = document.createElement('a');
        var href = dataURL
        e.setAttribute('href', href);
        e.setAttribute('download', "FILE NAME.png");
        document.body.appendChild(e);
        e.click();
        document.body.removeChild(e);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work if the element you want to bind the click event to already exists:

```
var url = canvas.toDataURL();
var link = document.getElementById('-insert a element id here');
link.download = "DownloadName";
link.href = url;
```

This will create the data url, then assign it to the `href` of whatever link you have if it already exists, you just need to replace `'-insert a element id here'` with the id of the link you want it to be assigned to.

Alternatively if it doesn't exist you could do:

```
var url = canvas.toDataURL();
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = "DownloadName";
link.href = url;
link.innerHTML = "Download";
document.getElementById('-insert parent element here-').appendChild(link);
```

This will create the data url, then create an `a` element, set its `download`, `href` and `innerHTML` properties and insert it in the DOM. Just replace `'-insert parent element here-'` with whatever element you want the link to be inside.

Comment: These are both good but they need the user to download the file with a click. This looks ok, http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php.

Comment: Okay, no problem. But I have made some changes based on your comment if you did want to use JS.